# Delphi TObjectDictionary inheritance

Tags: dictionary, delphi, generics, inheritance

Is TObjectDictionary class inheritance allowed / supported in Delphi Berlin ?

I have a number of classes of the form

```
TClass1 = class( TObject )
  ID : Cardinal;
end;

TDictionaryClass = class( TObjectDictionary<Cardinal, TClass1>)
end;

TClass2 = class( TClass1 )
end;

TDictionaryClass2 = class( TDictionaryClass )
end;

var
  dc2 : TDictionaryClass2;
```

When creating and adding objects of type TClass2 to TDictionaryClass2 all seeems to be working normally and the instance of TDictionaryClass2 has the correct count. However operations such as dc2.Keys.ToArray lead to access violations.
I have a lot of base functions in TDictionaryClass so the above construction is convenient but is it legal and if so what is causing the Keys array to be inaccessible ?

If this is not possible is there another mechanism for declaring a base class with the majority of common functionality whilst retaining the typed dictionary appearance of descendents ?

Comment: Yes, inheritance works. Please show [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code shown here. These patterns of inheritance are perfectly normal and widely used.

Clearly you have a defect in your code but it's not to be found in the code shown here. You'll need to debug your code.